# Adding a value from a drop down to any set of values from another drop down in KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

(Update)
I've been practicing KOjs and I've been curious with some complex things.

[Take this example (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/yku33mtq/4/)

That's the original work.  There's a text output where it's values are being read from a drop down.  Each item on the drop down has a number value, and is being formatted (using numeralJS) into the text. Then a a single character shows up at the bottom, corresponding to the optionText value of the dropdown.

Now, here's what I did: I added a new drop down where there are also pre-define values:

```
var x = 300;
var y = 1234;
var z = 78;
```

The select tag is just beside the original select tag:

```
<select id="addThis" data-bind="options: addToThisSet, optionsText: 'numType', value: setNumValue"></select>

<select id="theList" data-bind="options: htmlSelectSet, optionsText: 'theText', value: displayTheValue"></select>


<p><span data-bind="text: charSymbol"></span></p>
```

I tried to add the array of contents for the new `select` tag, in the same format as the original (I had a bad feeling about it.  Is this right?)

```
self.addToThisSet = [{
        numType: "item 1",
        NumValue: x
    }, {
        numType: "item 2",
        NumValue: y
    }, {
        numType: "item 3",
        NumValue: z
    }];
    self.setNumValue = ko.observable();

    self.htmlSelectSet = [{
        theText: "alpha",
        theValue: num1
    }, {
        theText: "bravo",
        theValue: num2
    }];
    self.displayTheValue = ko.observable();
```

My goal is pretty simple: whatever value is selected on `setNumValue()` (*item 1 or item 2 or item 3*) will be added to whatever value has been set on `displayValue()` (*alpha or bravo*) and output their result on `<h4 data-bind="text: sumOfValue"></h4>`

I thought it's just as simple as making another ko.computed that adds the variable selected and returning them:

```
self.sumOfValue = ko.computed(function () {
        sumCont = numeral(self.setNumValue() + self.displayTheValue()).format('0,0');
        return sumCont;
    });
```

But obviously it didn't work.
[This is what I'm trying to add and do (and failed) (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/vm7488/yku33mtq/7/)

I need an Obi-Wan-Kenobi for this.  Help! :(

===============================
(previous)

I had this to start on: http://jsfiddle.net/yku33mtq/1/

on that Fiddle, I had a Number value being displayed dynamically on choice in the `Select` drop down - then a character is displayed to designate your choice in the `Select` drop down at the bottom.

I tried to add another `select` Drop down beside the number, and it broke :(

```
<h4 data-bind="text: sumOfValue"></h4><select id="addThis" data-bind="options: addToThisSet, optionsText: 'numType', value: setNumValue"></select>

<select id="theList" data-bind="options: htmlSelectSet, optionsText: 'theText', value: displayTheValue"></select>


<p><span data-bind="text: charSymbol"></span></p>
```

Basically, the new drop down will have number value as well, and these numbers depending on your choice, will be added to the current number from the next `select` drop down.

see [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yku33mtq/4/)

It also looks like the script started to fail as soon as I added the new `select` on the HTML without even placing the changes on the JS yet (http://jsfiddle.net/yku33mtq/5/) :/

What's the proper way and what's the rule on adding two drop downs that can be dynamic in KnockoutJS?

Comment: Check your browser's javascript console! You will see the error: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: setNumValue is not defined' which is comming from your `sumOfValue` computed. Where you need to write: `sumCont = numeral(self.setNumValue() + self.displayTheValue()).format('0,0');` http://jsfiddle.net/0c96mwLp/

Comment: I also tried adding the setNumValue().numValue to it and that "not defined" error returned.  Hmmm... it looks like the structure overall is bad, it can't read the number values anymore as soon as it steps out of the variable declaration.

Comment: @vm7488 Did you modify the sumOfValue computed function like so: http://jsfiddle.net/s05sL1ke/

Comment: Yes I did.  Now my only problem with the structure is getting it to read the numbers and summing them up. I highly suspect that the whole structure of the view model needs to change :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were merely forgetting to access the object properties in your computed.
In your select, the entire object is inserted into the `value` bound observable.

Therefore, you need to access `self.setNumValue().NumValue`.

I made a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yku33mtq/9/

HTML:

```
<h4 data-bind="text: sumOfValue"></h4>
<select id="addThis" data-bind="options: addToThisSet, 
                                optionsText: 'numType',     
                                value: setNumValue"></select>
<select id="theList" data-bind="options: htmlSelectSet, 
                                optionsText: 'theText',
                                value: displayTheValue"></select>
<p><span data-bind="text: charSymbol"></span></p>
```

JS:

```
function thisViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.addToThisSet = [{
        numType: "item 1",
        NumValue: 300
    }, {
        numType: "item 2",
        NumValue: 1234
    }, {
        numType: "item 3",
        NumValue: 78
    }];
    self.setNumValue = ko.observable();

    self.htmlSelectSet = [{
        theText: "alpha",
        theValue: 35450
    }, {
        theText: "bravo",
        theValue: 2450
    }];
    self.displayTheValue = ko.observable();

    self.sumOfValue = ko.computed(function () {
        var numValue = self.setNumValue();
        var display = self.displayTheValue();
        if (numValue && display) {
            return numValue.NumValue + display.theValue;
        }
    });

    self.charSymbol = ko.computed(function () {
        if (self.displayTheValue()) {
            if (self.displayTheValue().theText == "alpha") {
                return "A";
            }
            if (self.displayTheValue().theText == "bravo") {
                return "B";
            }
        }
        return null;
    });

}

ko.applyBindings(new thisViewModel());
```

Comment: Nice! You mean http://jsfiddle.net/yku33mtq/8/ Anyway, I thought the view model was wrong, it was just a wrong variable call.  Thanks man! I really appreciate it.  So basically, I have the computed variable to get two blank variables that will take `self.setNumValue();` and `self.displayTheValue();` then verify if both have values - then return them as numValue.NumValue + display.theValue ---- weird... why can't self.setNumValue().NumvValue work instead??

Comment: Hey, @vm7488, anytime! I make this kind of mistake approximately 72 times every day, hah.
If you could accept the answer, though, I'd be very grateful :)

Comment: @vm7488 accessing the variable directly can work... **if** you can guarantee that the observable never will have an `undefined` value. However, as your observables start empty, you must first check that both have values before accessing them. Got it? Also, in Knockout, it is a common practice to declare which observables you'll need right on top of the computed declaration. This makes the dependencies clear.

Comment: Looks like I got it. This works (but yeah, making 2 new smaller var will have shorter code): 
`if (self.setNumValue() && self.displayTheValue()) {
            return numeral(self.setNumValue().NumValue + self.displayTheValue().theValue).format('0,0');
        }
        return null;`